# Best way to access subviews of views instantiated from XIB?

Tags: ios, ios7, uiview, xib, ios8

I'm instantiating multiple clone views from a XIB, like this:

```
UIView *view = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyNib" owner:self options:nil][0];
```

Then I need to access a subview (say, change a label) of every single of those views.
Connecting an element with IBOutlet wont work here (as the reference would be rewrite but the most recent view instantiated).

Here is my best shot at this so far:

```
for (UIView *subview in myView.subviews) {
    if ([subview.restorationIdentifier isEqualToString:@"myTargetElement"]) {
        // do something with the view
        break;
    }
}
```

So I'm basically iterating though subviews to find my element by restorationIdentifier. I wonder if there is a way to get a direct reference without iteration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use IBOutlets. They need to be made to the custom view subclass though, not to the view controller where you add the view. Something like this works fine,

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "RDView.h"

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    RDView *view = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"RDView" owner:self options:nil][0];
    [self.view addSubview:view];
    view.topLabel.text = @"Hello";
    view.bottomLabel.text = @"Goodbye";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with reference by outlet? I think it'll work just as fine.
It just matters on how you do the dot referencing.

Example:

```
UIView *view = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyNib" owner:self options:nil][0];
//...
UIView *view_1 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyNib" owner:self options:nil][0];
//...
[view.someLabel setText:@"1"];
[view_1.someLabel setText:@"2"];
```

---

Anyways... alternatively, you can give the `subview`s a specific tag and access them via the `-viewWithTag:` method.

Example:

Say a `UILabel` in this '`MyNib`' of yours has a tag 100, then you can reference it via:

```
[view viewWithTag:100];

//like so:
//UILabel *lblTemp = [view viewWithTag:100];
//[lblTemp setText:@"NewText"];
```